# Writing $15x^2 + 15y^2 -16x + 16y -2xy -48 = 0$ in the form $\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y-y_0)^2}{b^2} = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, geometry, conic-sections

I have the equation $$15x^2 + 15y^2 -16x + 16y -2xy -48 = 0$$ I want to represent it in the plane, for that goal I want to find its general formula $$\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y-y_0)^2}{b^2} = 1$$ I would have no problems completing squares if it wasn't for this $2xy$.

For the sake of clearness, this problem is from the book "Complex variable analysis" that asks the representation of
$$|z-1| + |z+i| = 4$$ and after some trivial counts you end up in the first equation given.

Comment: It is rotated. That form that you want will need to be in new coordinates. You can find $x'=ax+by$, $y'=-bx+ay$, for some $a,b$ with $a^2+b^2=1$ to get rid of the $xy$ term (the $x'y'$ term really). You can plug those changes of variables there and solve for $a,b$ in the equation that makes the coefficient of $x'y'$ equal $0$. Do you know about eigenvectors?

Comment: Also note that you have modelled the original problem into a new problem. The original problem can be solved in other ways. The equation $|z-1|+|z+i|=4$ can be interpreted geometrically, directly. It is saying that the sum of the distances from $z$ to the points $1$ and $-i$ is $4$. This is the geometric definition of an ellipse with foci at $1$ and $-i$. With the $4$ you can find the vertices.

Comment: @baristocronaYou may look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_axis_theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation

$ | z - 1 | + | z + i | = 4 $

means that the distance of $z = x + i y = (x, y)$ (in the complex plane) from the point A(1, 0) plus the distance between $z$ and B(0, -1) is equal to $4$.  By definition, this means that $z$ lies on an ellipse whose foci are $A$ and $B$, and whose major axis length is 4.  Hence if you set up a second coordinate frame $C x' y' $ with its origin at the midpoint of $AB$, i.e. at $C = (0.5, -0.5)$ and whose $x'$ axis extends along $AB$, i.e. along (1, 1), then the equation of the ellipse becomes

$ \dfrac{x'^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{y'^2}{b^2} = 1 $

where $a = \dfrac{4}{2} = 2 $, and $ a^2 - b^2 = c^2 $

$c$ is the distance between the center $C$ and one of the foci, i.e.

$ c = AC = \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2} $

Therefore,  $b^2 = 4 - \dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{7}{2} $

Now the equation of the ellipse is completely specified.

---

Alternatively, from the equation

$ 15 x^2 + 15 y^2 -16 x + 16 y -2xy - 48 = 0 $

Define $ r = [x, y ]^T $, and

$ Q = \begin{bmatrix} 15 && -1 \\ -1 && 15 \end{bmatrix} $

$ b = [-16, 16 ]^T $

$ c = -48 $

Then the given equation can be written in matrix-vector form as

$ r^T Q r + b^T r + c = 0 $

First, find the center of the ellipse, which is given by

$ C = - \dfrac{1}{2} Q^{-1} b = [ 0.5 , -0.5 ] $

Now, we can re-write the above equation as,

$ (r - C)^T Q (r - C) + c - C^T Q C = 0 $

The constant $c - C^T Q C = -48 - 8 = -56 $

Finally diagonalize $Q$. i.e. write it as follows

$ Q = R D R^T $  where $R$ is a suitable rotation matrix, and $D$ is a diagonal matrix of $Q$'s eigenvalues.

If we define $ \theta = \dfrac{1}{2} \tan^{-1} \bigg( \dfrac{ 2(-1) }{15 - 15 } \bigg) = \dfrac{\pi}{4} $

Then the rotation matrix $R$ is

$R =  \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta && - \sin \theta \\ \sin \theta && \cos \theta \end{bmatrix} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && -1 \\ 1 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

And $ D = \begin{bmatrix} D_{11} && 0 \\ 0 && D_{22} \end{bmatrix} $

where

$D_{11} = 15 \cos^2 \theta + 15 \sin^2 \theta + 2 (-1) \cos \theta \sin \theta = 14$

$ D_{22} = 15 \sin^2 \theta + 15 \cos^2 \theta - 2 (-1) \cos \theta \sin \theta = 16 $

i.e.

$ D = \begin{bmatrix} 14 && 0 \\ 0 && 16 \end{bmatrix} $

Thus far, we have the following equation,

$ (r - C) R D R^T (r - C) = 56 $

One final step, is to normalize the right hand side,

$ (r - C) R (D / 56) R^T (r - C) = 1 $

where

$ E = D / 56 = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1}{4} && 0 \\ 0 && \dfrac{ 2 }{7 } \end{bmatrix} $

Therefore, if we define the vector variable $ u = R^T (r - C) $, then

we will have

$ u^T E u = 1 $

i.e.

$ \dfrac{ u_1^2 } {4 } + \dfrac{ u_2^2 } { (7/2) } = 1 $

Thus $ a^2 = 4 , b^2 = \dfrac{7}{2} $

The coordinates $u = (u_1, u_2)$ are centered at $C= [0.5, -0.5] $ and related to the $[x, y]$ coordinate axes by a rotation about $C$ by an angle of $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{4} $.